# How do I set an nginx rewrite rule for my project that contains both client and server code?

Tags: apache, nginx, mod-rewrite

I have a file structure that looks like this

```
demo
|+ build
| |+ images
| | |- logo.png
| |+ static
|   |+ css
|   | |- style.css
|   |+ js
|   |- index.html
|+ controllers
  |+ api
    |- users.php
```

Here's a map that how I want to setup my apache vhosts.

- All the normal paths need to be redirected to `build/index.html`
- Resource paths(ends with `.*`) need to be redirected to `build/**` and keep the file path
- APIs(starts with `/api/**`) need to be redirected to `controllers/api/**`

| url | path |
| --- | --- |
| `https://demo.com/` | `build/index.html` |
| `https://demo.com/users` | `build/index.html` |
| `https://demo.com/users/16` | `build/index.html` |
| `https://demo.com/images/logo.png` | `build/images/logo.png` |
| `https://demo.com/static/css/style.css` | `build/static/css/style.css` |
| `https://demo.com/api/users` | `controllers/api/users` |

---

#### Edit

After a lot of attempts I created the apache vhost like this and it kinda works. Is it the right way to do it? I don't have much experience on server-side.

Now I have to achieve the same with nginx since my real server is using nginx. How do I do the same with nginx settings?

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
    DocumentRoot "/Users/hao/Projects/demo" 
    ServerName demo.dev
    Options FollowSymLinks 
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteRule ^(?!/?api/)(.*\.\w+)$ /build/$1 [L] 
    RewriteRule ^(?!/?api/|/?$) /build/index.html [L] 
    RewriteRule ^/?api/(.*)$ /controllers/api/$1 [QSA,NE,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: This can be done, but *should* it be done? IMO, this is kinda now throwing out how a traditional web server works by handling a request at a specific URL, which usually is built on the pathing of the directory. 

Is there a reason why you cannot just take everything out of the build folder and put it in the root? Likewise for the controller folder, just remove it and put it in the root. If I am understanding you right, you will not even need to use rewrites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you can just use `/Users/hao/Projects/demo/build` as your root. Assuming you have only PHP files under `/Users/hao/Projects/demo/controllers/api` directory, you can try the following configuration:

```
server {
    server_name demo.dev;
    root /Users/hao/Projects/demo/build;
    index index.html;
    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }
    location ~ ^/api/.+\.php$ {
        root /Users/hao/Projects/demo/controllers;
        try_files $uri =404;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        fastcgi_pass <socket path or ip:port to PHP-FPM daemon here>;
    }
}
```